# Media stream daemon (mstreamd) stalling /restrarting during streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, xcode7-beta5

Our Objective C app (compiled on Xcode 7 beta, compatible with iOS 9) works well on all devices we tested on except **sometimes** on one, iPad 3 / iOS 8.1.1: When streaming online video files, sometimes files start after considerable delays or fail to start. This problem happens only on the mentioned device / iOS and only sometimes for some files.

The app heavily relies on video streaming so it is important we get this sorted.

There is nothing special about the files that sometimes get stuck while streaming down.

When the streaming stalls the following messages show in the log console:

> Aug 26 16:30:07 TEP-iPad-3 mstreamd[8043] : (Note ) mstreamd: mstreamd starting up.
>
> Aug 26 16:30:07 TEP-iPad-3 mstreamd[8043] : (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon starting...

The video player is created as follows:

```
vplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
```

where `mediaURL` is an `http://` address.

I'd appreciate tips on how to get to the bottom of this.